# I get a undefined in my React API component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an undefined when trying to use the search bar in my app.  The components compile fine in webpack.  I am not sure if I am having an es6 syntax issue or am missing something inside the operation of the components.

```
const axios = require('axios');

const OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_URL =
  'http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=5d0a2ef2cca550311d7015dc03763d54&units=imperial';

module.exports = {
  getTemp(location) {
    var encodedLocation = encodedURIComponent(location);
    var requestUrl = `${OPEN.WEATHER_MAP_URL}&q=${encodedLocation}`;

    axios.get(requestUrl).then((res) => {
      if (res.data.cod && res.data.message) {
        throw new Error(res.data.message)
      } else {
        return res.data.main.temp;
      }
      ((res) => {
        throw new Error(res.data.message);
      })
    })
  }
};
```

I get the error when I trigger the search in the search bar I get the undefined at var encodedLocation = encodedURIComponent(location);

I have tried using let and const instead of var, but this also did not help

Comment: small typo: encodeURIComponent

Comment: Which variable is not defined, ```location``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Fix a small typo:

Change

```
var encodedLocation = encodedURIComponent(location);
```

to

```
var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed that issue.